# Select menu for type field and map integers to text in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rubygems, formtastic

[I'm new to rails, and I hope it's not a silly question, seen a similar question but it's for PHP and doesn't help in my case]

To explain my problem, I'm using a analogy to users here. Lets say I have `users` table in my app, I have added a field called `user_type` to users table. Now I want to specify which type of user is.

lets say I have 5 types of users eg. moderator, administrator, consumer etc.

I don't want to make `user_type` field to be string type to store user type. Instead I want to make `user_type` to store `integer` and then **map these integer values to respective string values**.
Advantage to this approach is that I can change what a user type is called. Suppose that I no longer wish to call consumer a consumer and instead wish to call it something else.

I believe storing integer in db is better and gives some flexibility.

I know I can create select menu using formtastic(I'm using active_admin as admin panel, formtastic is used for forms)

```
 <%= f.input :user_type, :as => :select, :collection => { 
        0    => "Admin", 
        1   => "Moderator",
        2 => "Consumer",
    } %>
```

and then store values in db, and then select these users from db.

I want to know Is there a better way or approach to do it in rails or there is some gem available to do this or some other approach you prefer and why you recommend it.

I'm using postgresql as database.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I personally like the [active_enum](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum) gem combined to [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) because it's really simple to implement and they work fine together.

In your case, you would have to define an enum class like this :

```
class Type < ActiveEnum::Base
  value 1 => 'Admin'
  value 2 => 'Moderator'
  value 3 => 'Consumer'
end
```

Then in your `User` model, you simply add this :

```
enumerate :user_type, :with => Type
```

And what is really great with `simple_form` is that you simply have to call :

```
<%= f.input :user_type =>
```

to get a `select` with all your values.

Comment: Appears to be nice solution, tried and it works but select menu is not working. probably it's not compatible with formtastic.

Comment: Actually it is, check the `active_enum` documentation, section 'Form helpers'. You just need to require the appropriate extension in your `config/initializers/active_enum.rb` : `require 'active_enum/form_helpers/formtastic2'` if you're using Formtastic 2.x

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
# user.rb
USER_TYPES = { moderator: 1, superuser: 2, admin: 3, client: 4 }

# views
select :user, :user_type, User::USER_TYPES
```

This saves the integer values to the database.  If you want to get the the string equivalent, use `User::USER_TYPES.key(@user.user_type)`

EDIT: forgot to add scopes

```
scope :moderators, where(user_type: USER_TYPES[:moderator])
scope :superusers, where(user_type: USER_TYPES[:superuser])
...
```

or

```
USER_TYPES.each do |user_type, value|
  scope :"#{user_type}s", where(user_type: USER_TYPES[user_type])
end
```